# How to remove main[DEBUG] lines from console while running maven clean install

Tags: maven

While running Maven `clean install` command, I get a whole lot of these set of lines on the console, which is consuming too much space. I have tried using the maven command to remove debug statements, but they are still there.

```
[main] DEBUG 
117  [main] DEBUG 
219  [main] DEBUG 
313  [main] DEBUG 
415  [main] DEBUG 
539  [main] DEBUG 
629  [main] DEBUG
```

Comment: Did you have a look at the processed file on th given line number?

Answer (score 0):

Run maven with the -q or --quiet parameter, will show only errors.

Answer (score 0):

This maven command will enough for you

```
mvn validate clean install | egrep -v "(^\[INFO\]|^\[DEBUG\])"
```

From this resource: http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html#running-sect-verbose-option

```
-e for error
-X for debug
-q for only error
```